# Why is "fais" needed in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques, conjugaison

Why is "fais" needed in this sentence?

> Tu ne fais qu'écrire des commentaires.

Écrire can be conjugated alone in the sentence.

"Ne que" means "just" in French, but it is perfectly fine to use "n'ecris pas" to express yourself.

Translation: You are doing writing reviews.

Comment: I suggest that you spell explicitly the phrase and the alternative phrase in your questions - sometimes they are hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

- Tu ne fais qu'écrire des commentaires !

Among  the things  you do there is  no activity different from that  of writing  comments.

- Tu n'écris que des commentaires !

The only  type of writing you do  is the writing of comments, you write  nothing else but comments.

Answer (score 1):

*Tu ne fais qu'écrire des commentaires.* = You do nothing but writing comments.
The sentence requires a verb, which in this case is *faire*=do.

Comment: Whereas *Tu n'écris que des commentaires* is the alternative and means "All you write is comments"

Comment: @LukeSawczak Agreed. Thanks. These are two different ways of saying the same thing - in French, as well as in English.

Comment: "suggest that you spell explicitly the phrase and the alternative phrase in your questions - sometimes they are hard to understand."


Roger please explain this

Comment: @Brian you are not satisfied with one phrase (containing *fais*) and you suggest constructing a phrase without it... but not clear which. Combined with very cryptic English it makes your posts incomprehensible (*"ne que" Means just in french, but it is perfectly fine to use "n'ecris pas" to express your self.* - ???) I am not trying to offend you, but simply suggesting how you can generate more answers, answers of better quality, and hopefully some upvotes (which are necessary, so that you are not eventually blocked for asking poor questions.)

Comment: @Brian: one thing very confusing about your question is you say "Translation: You are doing writing reviews." This is not the translation of any French sentence you have in your question. Do you think "You are just doing writing reviews" (I added "just") is the translation of "tu ne fais qu'écrire des commentaires !"? If so, you should say that. Otherwise, you should say what the original French is for this "translation". And please edit your question rather than replying in comments.